# Unity find position within range of object

Tags: unity, vector

Say you have a gameobject that is at a certain position(this could be your player).

Now say that you have a melee NPC that has to be within a certain range to hit the Player.

Now you would do something like this to find out where the player is:

```
var targetPosition = target.transform.position;
```

Say that the range of the NPC is 4 meaning he can be 4 units away from the player before he can start attacking him.

My question is how would you subtract that to get a position that is within range?

And am i doing this type of thing correctly? or is there a better way of doing it?  :)

Any help would be appriciated a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) to get the distance between two positions.

```
float distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(playerPosition, targetPosition);
float distanceThreshold = 4f;
if (distanceToTarget <= distanceThreshold) {
    // Attack
}
```